# Return string when no results

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the correct way to return a string when no results are returned.
The following isn't working

```
SELECT 
TOP 1 CASE
WHEN
    CustomerName IS NULL
        THEN 
            'Unknown'
WHEN
    CustomerName = ''
        THEN
            'Unknown'
ELSE 
    CustomerName
END
AS
CustomerName FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CustomerCode = 222
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the DISTINCT TOP 1.  I believe you need an order by so you know which TOP that is referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to return `Unknown` when there are no rows in your table that have `CustomerName` that's not `NULL` or not `''`.

```
SELECT COALESCE((SELECT TOP 1 CustomerName FROM 
            CUSTOMER WHERE CustomerCode = 222
            AND CustomerName IS NOT NULL
            AND CustomerName <> ''),'Unknown') CustomerName
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question, you want to return a value even when the WHERE clause doesn't match, and you want 'Unknown' to replace the empty string or a NULL value:

```
SELECT TOP 1 COALESCE(NULLIF(CustomerName,''),'Unknown')
FROM (
  SELECT CustomerName FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CustomerCode = 222
  UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL
) t
ORDER BY CustomerName DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this may be it's work..

```
    SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1 CASE WHEN ISNULL(CustomerName,'') <>'' THEN CustomerName ELSE 'Unknown'
 END as CustomerName FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CustomerCode = 222
```

or

```
SELECT TOP 1 CustomerName FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1 CASE WHEN ISNULL(CustomerName,'') <>'' THEN CustomerName ELSE 'Unknown'
 END as CustomerName ,1 No FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CustomerCode = 222
UNION 
SELECT 'Unknown',2)
AS T ORDER BY No
```